# Firebase Realtime Queries with indexes In php

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing an issue while applying queries on firebase data in PHP.

I want to get online users list from the above offline and online data
that is stored in firebase
actually under user_list I have added user's ids that is dynamic/variables so I can't apply rule on the behalf of this.

```
[
user_list=>[1 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'abbas', 'status' => 'online'], 2 => ['id' => 2, 'naumani' => '1.0,2.0', 'status' => 'online'], 3 => ['id' => 3, 'dev' => '1.0,2.0', 'status' => 'offline'], 4 => ['id' => 4, 'dev' => '1.0,2.0', 'status' => 'offline']]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solutions from the documentations:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#section-indexing-order-by-value

The example of dinosaurs was very helpful for me.
Steps:

1. set the rule first:
2. Then in Admin SDK use orderByChild (Mine is PHP)